# UnknownError when trying to use a pre-trained model to predict classes

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Using the below tutorial, I've tried to save a pre-trained model into a .h5 file using the `model.save()`.
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_restore_models#save_the_entire_model

I've loaded this model in a new document using `load_model()` and when I'm trying to use it to predict on new data, I'm getting an UnknownError. I am using `tensorflow-gpu`.

The code I've used for training the model is as below:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Embedding, CuDNNLSTM, Bidirectional
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

"""
My dataset is a two-column DataFrame of which the first column (X) contains
a pre-processed and encoded tweet which has been padded to a length of 47 words. The reason as to why I did this is because I'm passing in these values to an Embedding layer
The second column (Y) is a label associated with that tweet

X_train.shape = (89552, 47)
Y.shape = (89552,)

vocab_size = 66167
max_sent_len = 47
emd_dim = 75
"""
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=420)

x_train, x_val, Y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.1, random_state=420)

model = Sequential([
    Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=emb_dim, input_length=max_sent_len, trainable=True),
    Bidirectional(CuDNNLSTM(64, return_sequences=False)),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(2, activation='softmax')
])
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, Y_train, epochs=50, batch_size=300, shuffle=True, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))

model.summary()

model.save('trained/model-2-f.h5')
```

I am not getting any errors when trying to use this model for predictions.

I'm trying to test whether this model has been saved properly in another file and using another dataset of the same properties to test it on.

```py
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

trained_model = load_model('trained/model-2-f.h5')

"""
w_x is the data I'm using to predict values for

w_x.shape = (201, 47)
"""

w_pred = trained_model.predict_classes(w_x)
```

The error I'm getting is:

```py
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-cd338bbebc52> in <module>
----> 1 w_pred = trained_model.predict_classes(w_x)
      2 w_pred

~\Anaconda3\envs\nlp\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py in predict_classes(self, x, batch_size, verbose)
    316         A numpy array of class predictions.
    317     """
--> 318     proba = self.predict(x, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=verbose)
    319     if proba.shape[-1] > 1:
    320       return proba.argmax(axis=-1)

~\Anaconda3\envs\nlp\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in predict(self, x, batch_size, verbose, steps, callbacks, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1076           verbose=verbose,
   1077           steps=steps,
-> 1078           callbacks=callbacks)
   1079 
   1080   def reset_metrics(self):

~\Anaconda3\envs\nlp\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training_arrays.py in model_iteration(model, inputs, targets, sample_weights, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, val_inputs, val_targets, val_sample_weights, shuffle, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, mode, validation_in_fit, prepared_feed_values_from_dataset, steps_name, **kwargs)
    361 
    362         # Get outputs.
--> 363         batch_outs = f(ins_batch)
    364         if not isinstance(batch_outs, list):
    365           batch_outs = [batch_outs]

~\Anaconda3\envs\nlp\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   3290 
   3291     fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals,
-> 3292                                 run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   3293     self._call_fetch_callbacks(fetched[-len(self._fetches):])
   3294     output_structure = nest.pack_sequence_as(

~\Anaconda3\envs\nlp\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1456         ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(self._session._session,
   1457                                                self._handle, args,
-> 1458                                                run_metadata_ptr)
   1459         if run_metadata:
   1460           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

UnknownError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Unknown: Fail to find the dnn implementation.
     [[{{node bidirectional_2/CudnnRNN_1}}]]
     [[dense_2/Softmax/_243]]
  (1) Unknown: Fail to find the dnn implementation.
     [[{{node bidirectional_2/CudnnRNN_1}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```